# How to filter VARCHAR(50) date column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a table using `BULK INSERT` from a CSV file. I tried with date but couldn't get through. It was giving me error, so tried with `TradeDate varchar(50)` and everything worked and saved  '11012012' in Tradedate column.

But, when I tried to retrieve the data using select query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM FundTranTest 
WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME, RIGHT(TradeDate,4)  + Left(TradeDate, 2)  + SUBSTRING(TradeDate, 3, 2))
      < '2012-12-29'
```

I received this error:

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
>   The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

How to get this done? Any help would be great.

then tried to update table with adding the date column:

```
ALTER TABLE FundTranTest ADD TDate Date

WITH Udata AS 
( select TradeDate as rcol 
  from FundTranTest
)
UPDATE FundTranTest SET TDate = CONVERT(DATETIME,RIGHT(rcol,4)+Left(rcol,2)+SUBSTRING(rcol,3,2)) 
FROM Udata u
where FundTranTest.TradeDate  = u.rcol
```

but its not working ....

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) - you should always use the most appropriate data type - that's what they're there for, after all!

Comment: globalization settings? eg, is SQL set to american date format where your CSV is in UK format? If you save your dates as a long date string then SQL can work it out much easier. eg '11 Jan 2012'

Comment: Please make an effort to format and proof read your posts in the future. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for some tips.

Comment: If you must work with data like this, you will be miles better off converting this data into the correct datatypes and storing that into another table before doing any kind of query.

Comment: It sounds like some of your date rows that you're pulling in aren't in the same format, or are `Null`, etc.  Regardless, doing this comparison in your `WHERE` clause (even if it *did* work) would be murder on the database.  There is no way for the engine to use any kind of index or cached plan for this.  It will have to calculate that for every single row.

Comment: tried with adding new column with date TDate and converting this column to date column:ALTER TABLE FundTranTest ADD TDate Date and WITH Udata AS 
( select TradeDate as rcol 
  from FundTranTest
)
UPDATE FundTranTest SET TDate = CONVERT(DATETIME,RIGHT(rcol,4)+Left(rcol,2)+SUBSTRING(rcol,3,2)) 
FROM Udata u
where FundTranTest.TradeDate  = u.rcol without success

Comment: tried with UPDATE FundTranTest
SET TDate = CONVERT(DATETIME,RIGHT(i.TradeDate ,4)+Left(i.TradeDate,2)+SUBSTRING(i.TradeDate,3,2)) 
FROM ( SELECT TradeDate FROM FundTranTest) i
WHERE i.TradeDate = FundTranTest.TradeDate  but got error:Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 2
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the **error and the commentators have told you**, the data that you imported is **not in a valid date time format**. That is also why your update failed, the data itself is incorrect, that is the root cause of your problem and you need to fix the data before continuing.

You will need to do one of the following:

- Remove the imported data, correct the data in the CSV file by looking at where the values for `tradedate` are wrong, correcting them and then reimport the data into your table, but this time into the right data typed column (so not `varchar(50)`, but `datetime`).
- Determine what data in your current table is wrong, fix it to be in a correct format and then transform the current `tradedate` column from a `varchar(50)` into a `datetime` column.

Whichever method you decide upon, heed `@marc_s` words and link:

> [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)  you should always use the most appropriate data type - that's what they're there for, after all!

For some assistance incase you chose the second method, here are **SOME** hints as to how you can validate the information in the column, these do not begin to cover what all might be wrong with your data, but it should give you and idea as to what all else you can check for validation:

```
select tradedate,
       *
  from FundTranTest
 where -- Look for TradeDate's that are not even 8 chars long
       len(tradedate) <> 8
       -- Shows any years that are not starting with a 2
    or right(TradeDate, 4) not like '2%'
       -- Check that your months are correct
    or left(tradedate, 2) not in ('01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12')
       -- check that dates are correct
    or substring(tradedate, 3, 2) not in ('01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10',
                                          '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', 
                                          '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '16', '17', '18', '19', '30',
                                          '31')
```

Comment: HI BERND , THANKS FOR UR HELP. U SHED SOME LIGHT ON AND IT RESOLVED . CHEERS

Comment: No problem, but try and use less capital letters in the future please :)